# geocoder: distance sortable index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oop, geocoding, rails-geocoder

I'm developing a rails app where `Users` are having many `Items`. The users are geocoded thanks to another model I called `Place` that is relying on the ruby geocoder gem.

```
class Place < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :street_number, :street, :city, :postal_code, :country, :latitude, :longitude

    belongs_to :placable, :polymorphic => true
    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode

    def address
       [street_number, street, postal_code, city, country].compact.join(', ')
   end
 end
```

In the user model, I delegated methods from the `Place` model to be able to access them directly at the user level.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_one  :place, :as => :placable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :place
  attr_accessible :place_attributes

  geocoded_by :address
  delegate :address, :to => :place, :allow_nil => true
  delegate :latitude, :to => :place, :allow_nil => true
  delegate :longitude, :to => :place, :allow_nil => true
  #...
end
```

The same trick is used at the items level:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  # place
  geocoded_by :address
  delegate :place, :to => :user, :allow_nil => true 
  delegate :address, :to => :user, :allow_nil => true
  delegate :latitude, :to => :user, :allow_nil => true
  delegate :longitude, :to => :user, :allow_nil => true
  # ...
end
```

Now I'd like to set up an index on items such that they are sorted by distance to the current user. I don't find a design to perform the task in this setup.

I tried to do the following with the delegation of the `near` method from geocoder on the `User` model and the `Item`model but the sql query fails complaining that `latitude` and `longitude` are not columns of the `items` table. This is actually correct but I wish to access the ones in the `places`table instead.

```
  # this added to the user model:
  delegate :near :to => :place
  # this added to the item model:
  delegate :near :to => :user

  class ItemsController < ApplicationController

    def index
       @items=Item.near(current_user.place, params[:distance]).paginate(:per_page => 20, :page => params[:page_name])
    end
  end
```

I would like to avoid the solution where both users and items are having attributes for geocoding (latitude, longitude, address, etc.).

Comment: What database are you using? Postgres has a module for geographical information that might help solve your problem.

Comment: @dpassage - Im' indeed on Postgres. Could you give me more info on the module you mention? thks

Comment: Couple of things. There's PostGIS (http://postgis.refractions.net) for the hardcore, or the standard Postgres extension earthdistance (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/earthdistance.html) for the less hardcore.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know if it's too obvious to me or I'm wrong, but allow me try:

I'd just create a column(e.g, location - at Item model) to save the current location of the item and then compare it with the current user location.

Wasn't what you looked for? hope I helped!